# font-awesome icon with specific value(s)

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

Is there a way to give an icon (from font-awesome) specific value(s)?
I know there is a way to make the icons bigger, but is there a way to make them smaller? If there is, is there also a way to place this icon on a position you desire?

1 is what you get when you insert the font-awesome icon and 2 is what I try to achieve.

[image: What I am trying to get]

My code looks like this:

```
<h4> Wijzigingen <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"> </i> </h4>
```

The CSS styling comes with the font-awesome files:

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to reduce the `font-size` and also lift it up a little bit.

```
h4 {
    position: relative;
}

h4 .fa {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: -3px;
}
```

For lifting the icon up you can use position absolute like I have done here or you can keep your `display inline block` and use `margin-top: -5px` or something to lift it up.

Comment: Adding the positions and declaring the font-size is enough, the attributes top and right are not needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the icon a unique class:

```
<h4> Wijzigingen <i class="fa fa-circle custom-icon" aria-hidden="true"> </i> </h4>
```

And give the element a smaller font-size:

```
.custom-icon {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

You can change the font size to the size you want it be.

Answer (score 0):

Define class in h4 for adding fa icon class  Wijzigingen    otherwise it will apply in all h4 tags or you can also add parent div class & define it in css like (.divclass h4 & .divclass .fa.fa-circle ).

```
h4.Wijicon{
    position: relative;
}
h4.Wijicon .fa.fa-circle {
    top: -4px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```